# Terraform Modules - Add item after the fact

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I've been trying to figure this tad bit out with regard to terraform modules. I added in a Security group module into my code and deployed it. After its deployed, i have no way of adding a new rule to the group unless i taint the whole module and redeploy it. I've tried looking on google and cant really find an answer to this.

The only thing i can think of is adding a resource block after the fact to add the new rule... but doesn't that defeat the purpose of the module?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of the code im using. If i deploy this successfully, then go back and make a change, the change never gets read.

```
module "main_sg_web" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"

  name        = "Web SG"
  description = "Security group for Web Services with port 443 open within VPC"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["10.10.0.0/16"]
  egress_cidr_blocks  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ingress_rules       = ["https-443-tcp"]
  egress_with_cidr_blocks = [
    {
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      protocol    = "-1"
      description = "outbound traffic"
      cidr_blocks = "0.0.0.0/0"
    }
  ]
  tags = var.vpc_tags
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code of how your module is defined?
Have you tried using output variables in the module to expose the security groups?

Comment: Posted the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws/2.10.0/submodules/ssh?tab=outputs, the module outputs the security group ID

you can use https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group_rule.html to add a rule to it:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_all" {
  type            = "ingress"
  from_port       = 0
  to_port         = 65535
  protocol        = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks     = "10.0.0.0/8"
  security_group_id = ${module.main_sg_web.this_security_group_id}
}
```

Comment: Thats what i figured i may have to do for adding rules. Wanted to know if there was a way to just modify the module instead of adding more blocks. Oh well.